# NameError: global name 'client' is not defined

Tags: python, sockets

Using `tkinter`, when I try to open the client I get the error:

> NameError: global name 'client' is not defined

```
 Traceback(most recent call lost):
File "C:\Users\Gerardi\Desktop\graf2.py", line 21, in <module>
cliente2 = conectar()
File "C:\Users\Gerardi\Desktop\graf2.py", line 18, in conectar
cliente.connect(address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
ocket.error: [Errno 10049] La direcci¾n solicitada no es vßlida en este context

def conectar():
    cliente = socket.socket(2,1)
    ip = cuadro_texto3.get("1.0", "1.end")
    address = (ip, 5001)
    cliente.connect(address)
    return cliente

cliente2 = conectar() 

def check_message(cliente):
while True:
    try:
        datos = cliente.recv(1000)
        cuadro_texto2.insert("1.0", datos)
    except socket.error:
        break
    if datos == "quit":
        cliente.close()
        server.close()      
cliente.close()
```

Comment: the error states you are trying to use a variable `cliente` which is not defined. maybe you misspelled it, maybe you didn't initialize it before using it...  show the source of `check_message` if you need more help

Comment: You should have edited the question to add that code, it's unreadable here.

Comment: im really sorry about that, this is my first question here..

Comment: In check_message() function, add 'global cliente', so that cliente will be available in this function.

Comment: i got the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use *global* anyway. Use return values and parameters.

```
def conectar():
    [... your code ...]
    return cliente

def check_message(cliente):
    [... your code ...]

client = conectar()
check_message(client)
```

Additionally it might not be a good idea to close the connection in a function called *check_message*. You should have an own function for this.

Refactoring the whole code in a class might be a good idea in the long run.